# How to configure a list of CPUs using chcpu?

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, cpu

There is command chcpu. I know how to use this with one CPU number. How to use this with list or set of CPU numbers ?

```
chcpu -e cpu-list
```

How to write this cpu-list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man chcpu`

> Some options have a cpu-list argument.  Use this argument to specify a comma-separated list of CPUs.  The list can contain  indi‐
>          vidual CPU addresses or ranges of addresses.  For example, 0,5,7,9-11 makes the command applicable to the CPUs with the addresses
>          0, 5, 7, 9, 10, and 11.